# Blackberry/iPhone Development Sim on Windows

Tags: iphone, blackberry

I'm looking for a **free** solution just to learn how to develop applications for **Blackberry and iPhone** on **Windows** that **includes** a Blackberry and iPhone **simulator**.

The closest program I came across to this was DragonFireSDK but its not free. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For Blackberry the solution is free from RIM, Everything you need is on their [developer web site](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/).

Has for IPhone, you need MAC OS X. There may be other solution but I don't know them.